# macOS Reminders: every reminder appears twice

Tags: catalina, reminders

Since I updated my Mac to macOS 10.15 Catalina every reminder which are synchronised via my own WebDAV Server, appears twice in the Notification Center.

Like this:

[image: Image of double shown reminder in macOS 10.15 Catalina]

Before I updated the OS everything was fine; It seems like the competence for showing the reminders moved from the calendar app which shows the first notification to the official reminders app. Is there any way to avoid these double shown reminders without disabling all notifications for the calendar app?

Comment: I have the exact same issue and I also don't know how to fix it. I also happens to be my WebDAV server and not iCloud where these reminders reside. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I have the same issue and found the following: You can disable the notifications for the Reminder app and stick with the notifications of the Calendar app.
But this has one disadvantage: The “Complete” button of the Calendar notifications does _not_ mark the reminder completed.

Comment: Fortunately, since the last macOS update this issue is gone!

Comment: I am working on latest macOS Monterey 12.5 and the issue still persists. I synchronize with NextCloud. My solution so far was to "Ignore Alerts" of that calendar in the Calendar app. Downside: I don't get other notifications for that calendar either... Workaround could be: create a TODO calendar, ignore those alerts. So for instance: Private (only real events) and TodoPrivate (only TODOs, Calendar ignores alerts).